# Get a list of all Context session variables used

Tags: asp.net

For a webforms application we want to make the switch to use a state server for managing the session states of the application. For this, all used session variables need to be serializable.

For this reason we need to have a list of all variables/types used within the Http Session. As this is a Visual Studio solution which contains up to 80 projects we do not want to do this manually.

How can this be done? Is there an existing library that I can use?

Comment: did you check codedom ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom

Comment: No, any tips on how to use codedom for this purpose?